# Malloc nullifying previously allocated pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm currently building a binary search tree for a school project and ran into a small issue:

A function (key_gen) is being called to generate a key for the nodes which consists of a pair of strings. This works fine for the first two nodes; however, upon the third call of key_gen the key contained in the second node becomes null. Could somebody please explain why this is? Here are my functions:

```
void main(){
    BStree tst = bstree_ini();
    bstree_insert(tst,key_gen("a","a"),data_gen(1));
    bstree_insert(tst,key_gen("c","c"),data_gen(2));
    key_gen("b","b"); //Upon execution, the key generated from key_gen("c","c") goes null
}

BStree bstree_ini(){
    BStree toReturn;
    BStree_node *toAllocate =(BStree_node *)malloc(sizeof(BStree_node));
    toAllocate = NULL;
    toReturn = &toAllocate;
    return toReturn;
}

Key key_gen(char *skey1, char *skey2){
    Key toReturn;
    toReturn = (Key_Struct*)malloc(sizeof(Key_Struct));
    toReturn->skey1 = string_dup(skey1);
    toReturn->skey2 = string_dup(skey2);
    return toReturn;
}

char * string_dup(char *str){
   char *toReturn = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
   for(int i = 0; i<strlen(str)+1; i++){
       *(toReturn+i) = *(str+i);
   }
   return toReturn;
}

Data data_gen(int idata){
    Data toReturn;
    toReturn = (int *)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    *toReturn = idata;
}
```

And structures/typedefs:

```
typedef int* Data;

typedef struct {char *skey1;char *skey2;} Key_Struct;

typedef Key_Struct* Key;

typedef struct BStree_node{
Key key;
Data data;
struct BStree_node *left, *right;
} BStree_node;

typedef BStree_node** BStree;
```

I don't think the issue is with insert as my debugger shows all the variables are as expected until key_gen("b","b") is called, but I can provide the code for insertion if needed.

Thank you in advance

Edit:

I've added pictures to help clarify the issue
https://ibb.co/d5LRsLV
https://ibb.co/vCNKsNh

Comment: Why are you setting `toAllocate` to `NULL` in `bstree_ini()`? That's certainly incorrect. You're leaking the memory you just allocated and returning an invalid root for your tree.

Comment: That's actually a specification in the project.
 "Allocate memory of type BStree node*, set the value to NULL, and return a pointer to the
allocated memory." Is the description my prof gave for bstree_ini().

Comment: By set the value to NULL, I think the assignment means, init the memory to all zero that you've allocated.  Like where I used `calloc()` in my example below to do just that. BTW, there is no `bstree_insert()` function in your code, so I can't help you without that as the rest is just guessing.  It has to be a minimal, compilable, example if you really want more help.

Comment: BTW, `data_gen()` doesn't return any values.

Comment: That would make sense actually. I'll change it over to do that. Didn't include bstree_insert as I didn't think it would be needed. https://pastebin.com/yHyRKDGR this includes it and should be compilable -- the insert doesn't work perfectly yet, but should be enough to demonstrate the issue. Thanks again

Comment: @JohnH You're misunderstanding how pointers work. When you set a pointer to `NULL`, it doesn't put `NULL` into  the address pointed to by the pointer, it changes the value of the pointer so that it now points to address 0 (usually). So your  assignment isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: @user1118321 Yes, I understand that.  As you could see in the partial answer I wrote, below, based on the incomplete info from the poster, demonstrates NOT to set the pointer to NULL, but to use calloc to initialize the memory allocated to a known state - aka, all zeroed or NULL out.

Comment: `typedef int* Data;` can probably be `typedef int Data;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't allocating the BStree the way you think.  Here are the problems:

```
BStree bstree_ini(){
    BStree toReturn;
    BStree_node *toAllocate =(BStree_node *)malloc(sizeof(BStree_node));
    // Next line: you leak the memory allocated, 
    // and replace it with NULL yourself.  
    toAllocate = NULL;
    // Next line: the address of the pointer toAllocate is a local stack 
    // address and will cease to be valid once the routine returns.
    // (even though, if you allocated memory properly, you could return that)
    toReturn = &toAllocate;
    return toReturn;
}
```

You should try:

```
BStree_node bstree_ini(){
    return calloc(1, sizeof(BStree_node));
}
```

And then in main() (main has to return int btw):

```
  int main(void) {
    BStree_node tstnode = bstree_ini();
    BStree = &tstnode;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is with the Keys held in the tree though, not the nodes, although I agree that's a terrible way of initializing the tree. I'll try to add a screenshot of my variable in order to clarify the issue. Thanks for the response

Comment: Be careful with `calloc`, it sets the memory to 0, but it doesn't necessarily set the pointers to null, (if there are some in `BStree_node`,) http://c-faq.com/malloc/calloc.html.

Comment: Neil, while that advise is historically correct, it is all basically old history.  The implementations which represent NULL in ways other than zero are pretty much all at least as old as I am (nearing 50) if not older.  On modern machines (linux, macos, windows, hpux, aix, solaris, os400, ios, and android to name the ones I'm familiar with) calloc does set pointers to NULL, because all those architectures represent NULL with 0.

Comment: @JohnH Just wanted to say a quick thank you -- still don't fully understand why, but restarting from the top with your calloc suggestion fixed all the issues I was having. Cheers.